# Dynamically access array in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have an issue dynamically accessing an array in one of my views.

I begin by organizing the values I need easy access to into `$entityClubStats` like this:

```
$entityClubStats = [];
foreach($entity->clubs as $club) {
    $entityClubStats[$club->name] = [
        'days_to_pay' => $club->pivot->days_to_pay,
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Then I iterate the master list of clubs with the intent of filling in relevant values if they exist:

```
@foreach (Club::isIncludedInStats()->get() as $club)
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{$club->name}}" readonly />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Days to Pay</label>
    <input type="text" name="club_days_to_pay" value="{{$entityClubStats[$club->name]['days_to_pay']}}" />
</div>
<!-- ... -->
@endforeach
```

The problem is that while I've tried using `{{double_brackets}}` and `<?= standard_syntax ?>`, this segment results in a white screen:

`$entityClubStats[$club->name]['days_to_pay'];`

However, it *does* work when I simply hardcode the `$club->name`:

`$entityClubStats['AAA']['days_to_pay'];`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it died when it didn't see the `$club->name` it was looking for in `$entityClubStats`. Doh!